# Intersection of two Path in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Right now, I am working with bezier curves in fabric.js. Assuming, for instance, 3 of them, with intersections between them. I need to find the exactly crossing point and, even more difficult, draw the selection in other canvas. For fabric.path, I'm using

```
   perPixelTargetFind: true,
```

Image to clarify the situation:

[image: Crossing bezier curves]

Comment: Finding the intersection between bezier curves is rather hard (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052689/how-to-find-intersection-points-between-two-cubic-bezier-curve, for example), so I'd be (pleasantly) suprised if someone comes up with a ready-made solution to your problem.

Comment: You can find many different forms of Bézier intersection [here](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/). There's also a nice library wrapped up as an npm package [`svg-intersections`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-intersections). To use with Fabric you'll need to convert to SVG, find the intersections, and take back to Fabric land.

Comment: Note that it's not clear from your example why any particular segments are being chosen (drawn in red). Leftmost? Longest segments? Smallest angle of intersection? There are, to my mind, four possible ways of connecting those three paths.

Comment: My fault. The user must choose a part of a bezier to start but, for the moment i have enough whit find the intersection of the lines, clicking only in one of them. I will implement  kevLinDev library, to show some of result. Thank you very much for this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after a long time, I can't find any solution in fabric library, a workaround pass for convert to svg, use a another library or program your own proccess (pretty hard) and convert back to fabric.
The final solution is use paper.js, it has some functions to detect intersections and colissions, and, also, is very powerful for some other task.